# CentOS8: podman with enabled firewalld breaks DNS for container

Tags: centos8, podman

I just have started using CentOS8 + podman in scope of migration from CentOS7 + docker. The issue is the following:

1. When firewalld is stopped - DNS works fine inside container:

   ```
   [root@dev1 ~]# systemctl stop firewalld
   [root@dev1 ~]# podman run -it alpine ping gmail.com
   PING gmail.com (172.217.161.133): 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from 172.217.161.133: seq=0 ttl=54 time=6.027 ms
   64 bytes from 172.217.161.133: seq=1 ttl=54 time=5.892 ms
   64 bytes from 172.217.161.133: seq=2 ttl=54 time=5.757 ms
   ^C
   --- gmail.com ping statistics ---
   3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
   round-trip min/avg/max = 5.757/5.892/6.027 ms
   ```
2. But once firewalld is launched - DNS stop working inside container, even though network itself (ping) works fine:

   ```
   [root@dev1 ~]# systemctl start firewalld
   [root@dev1 ~]# podman run -it alpine ping gmail.com
   ping: bad address 'gmail.com'
   [root@dev1 ~]#
   [root@dev1 ~]#
   [root@dev1 ~]# podman run -it alpine ping 8.8.8.8
   PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=54 time=4.536 ms
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=54 time=7.059 ms
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=54 time=4.924 ms
   ^C
   --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
   3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
   round-trip min/avg/max = 4.536/5.506/7.059 ms
   ```
3. DNS can work fine in container when it is launched with --net=host param:

   ```
   [root@dev1 ~]# podman run -it --net=host  alpine ping gmail.com
   PING gmail.com (172.217.161.133): 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from 172.217.161.133: seq=0 ttl=55 time=4.981 ms
   64 bytes from 172.217.161.133: seq=1 ttl=55 time=5.445 ms
   64 bytes from 172.217.161.133: seq=2 ttl=55 time=4.635 ms
   ^C
   --- gmail.com ping statistics ---
   3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
   round-trip min/avg/max = 4.635/5.020/5.445 ms
   ```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:** As of 13/Dec/2020 this issue is not reproducible on "CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011".

Comment: I have the same problem. For now I solved by adding the CNI interface created by podman in the trusted zone of firewalld. I know it's a workaround, but I could not find any better solution.

Comment: I have the same problem, but somehow cannot find a working firewall rule to allow traffic. @ClaudioVenturini: can you share the rule you have used to work around this issue?

Comment: I simply did this: sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=cni-podman0

Comment: Could it be possible that this was fixed recently? Today I started up new CentOS8, and all podman containers are able to dns-resolve with firewalld turned on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just tested on "CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011" and seems all works good! And some off-topic: went to download CentOS latest ISO to test this issue and was shocked by this update: https://blog.centos.org/2020/12/future-is-centos-stream/